# Digicode in Nusmv

Tags: nusmv

i am new with NUSMV i am trying to modelise a digicode for reconize  41708 but user can't do more 3 error.
if you enter more 3 error the system go to state bloked to wait when you enter special code to be unblocked.
it is my code if you cant help me with idea and suggest code to finish .

```
MODULE main
VAR
val1 : {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
location : {E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,succes,blocked,unblocked,verified};
cpt : 0..3;
block : boolean;
NumberEnter : 0..5 ;


ASSIGN
init(cpt):=0;
init(block):=FALSE;
init(location):=E1;


next(location):= case 
        (location=E1) &(cpt!=3)  & (block!=TRUE) :E2 ;
        (location=E2) & (cpt!=3) & (block!=TRUE) :{E3,E1,blocked};

        (location=E3) & (cpt!=3) & (block!=TRUE) :{E2,E1,blocked} ;
        (location=E4) & (cpt!=3) & (block!=TRUE) :{E1,E5,blocked} ;
        (location=E5) & (cpt!=3) & (block!=TRUE) :{E1,blocked} ;
        TRUE:blocked;
        esac;


next(pas):= case 
            NumberEnter<5 :NumberEnter+ 1 ;

        TRUE:0;
        esac;
```

[Image of Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6PBo.jpg)

Comment: Your problem description is a bit too vague, what exactly is that you need help with? what works, what doesn't work? what would be the expected output? It is also completely unclear to me how should one unblock the device once one has inserted the incorrect input 3 times. Should the device immediately go to error state when an incorrect digit is pressed, or wait for all of them to be given as input? The system description appears to be a bit vague, can you refine it?

Comment: Model a code that recognizes code 41708. The system crashes after three unsuccessful attempts. In case of blocking, a special code can unlock the system.

Comment: @Lomrejaune: what code? one digit? another sequence of digits? -- you did not answer all other questions ~

Comment: yes I agree with you sorry for my expression I am not a native English speaker but French.

Comment: 1- Should the device immediately go to error state when an incorrect digit is pressed, or wait for all of them to be given as input? :  system must wait 5 digit enter before verifying if it's good

Comment: 2-It is also completely unclear to me how should one unblock the device once one has inserted the incorrect input 3 times : to unlock the system expect a special code that was not specified by the exercise

Comment: Are you set on your *finite state system* or would you be open to alternative approaches?

Comment: I'am open to alternative approaches . if you were in my case how you solve this model ? in Nusmv your answer can help me thank you for everything

Comment: I would take all 5 inputs at once, for example... that would simplify the model a lot. There is no good reason for examining one digit at a time after all..

Comment: ok I would understand better with a Nusmv example. I always try to understand by the code .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is:

```cpp
MODULE main()
VAR
    in_digit  : 0 .. 9;
    in_signal : boolean;
    dc : digicode(in_digit, in_signal);


MODULE digicode(in_digit, in_signal)
VAR
    state   : { RUN, OK, ERROR };
    idx     : 0 .. 4;
    counter : 0 .. 3;

DEFINE
    pwd := [4, 1, 7, 0, 8];

INIT state = RUN & idx = 0 & counter = 0;

ASSIGN
    next(state) := case
        state = RUN   & pwd[idx]  = in_digit & idx < 4     : RUN;
        state = RUN   & pwd[idx]  = in_digit               : OK;
        state = RUN   & pwd[idx] != in_digit & counter < 3 : RUN;
        state = RUN   & pwd[idx] != in_digit               : ERROR;
        state = ERROR & in_signal                          : RUN;
        TRUE                                               : state;
    esac;

    next(counter) := case
        state = RUN & pwd[idx] != in_digit & counter < 3 : counter + 1;
        state = RUN & pwd[idx]  = in_digit               : counter;
        TRUE                                             : 0;
    esac;

    next(idx) := case
        state = RUN & pwd[idx]  = in_digit & idx < 4 : idx + 1;
        state = RUN & pwd[idx] != in_digit           : 0;
        TRUE                                         : 0;
    esac;

--
-- the following invariants nicely restrict the set of viable
-- transitions when inputs can be ignored
--
INVAR
    in_signal     -> state = ERROR;

INVAR
    state = ERROR -> in_digit = 0;

INVAR
    state = OK    -> in_digit = 0;
```

The solutions assumes that one can only enter one digit at a time, through input `in_digit`, and that there is a separate control signal `in_signal` to reset the device.

The device has three possible states:

- `RUN`: the device reads an input digit from `in_digit`, and compares it with a fixed password sequence
- `OK`: the device recognized the input sequence some time in the past, and it is now ignoring any further input
- `ERROR`: the user made too many incorrect input attempts, and the device is ignoring any input digit until `in_signal` is `true`.

At the end of the model, I added three `INVAR` constraints which prune the transition space from edges that are not relevant to us because of some inputs being ignored at certain moments. Ignoring those inputs makes it much easier to simulate the system by hand.

The run the example, use `NuSMV`:

```
~$ NuSMV -int
~$ reset; read_model -i digicode.smv; go; pick_state -iv; simulate -iv -k 30
~$ quit
```

---

An alternative, and much simpler approach, would be to provide `digicode` with 5 input digits all at once. In this way, one can remove `idx` and `pwd` from the model, making it much simpler.

Comment: you're just great! this will take me a little while to understand but I understood the method!